# how do I make an input form clickable?

Tags: html, css

I have been given a problem to solve an issue. The task is to make the input form clickable. but I can't figure out what's going on in the code. It's the first time I'm seeing such code. Can somebody help me?

```html
<div class="container-center-horizontal">
  <form class="android-frontpage screen" onclick="window.open('javascript:SubmitForm(%27form2%27)', '_self');" name="form2" action="form2" method="post">
    <div class="overlap-group">
      <a href="javascript:SubmitForm('form2')" onclick="window.event.stopPropagation()"><img class="android-frontpage-1" src="https://anima-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/6162fec6f667ec5b97a58c2b/releases/6163081a3beef0eaf8ca4199/img/android---frontpage@2x.jpg" /> </a><img class="kid-pic-1" src="https://anima-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/6162fec6f667ec5b97a58c2b/releases/6163081a3beef0eaf8ca4199/img/kid-pic-1@2x.png"
      />
      <div class="rectangle-9"></div>
      <img class="rectangle-8" src="https://anima-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/6162fec6f667ec5b97a58c2b/releases/6163081a3beef0eaf8ca4199/img/rectangle-8@4x.png" />
      <p class="text-1">Join our community to get early access.</p>
      <div class="rectangle-4x input"></div>

      <div class="text-2">Enter your email address</div>




      <div class="rectangle-4"></div>
      <div class="get-started valign-text-middle">Get Started</div>
      <img class="evolvere-academy" src="https://anima-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/6162fec6f667ec5b97a58c2b/releases/6163081a3beef0eaf8ca4199/img/evolvere-academy@1x.png" />
      <div class="courses montserrat-bold-white-14px">Courses</div>
      <div class="blogs montserrat-bold-white-14px">Blogs</div>
      <div class="our-story montserrat-bold-white-14px">Our Story</div>
      <div class="contact-us montserrat-bold-white-14px">Contact Us</div>
      <h1 class="text-3">Building Education Of The Future!</h1>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: please be more specific. what do you mean with make it clickable? what is supposed to happen if you click on the form? Please also read: [Can I just link to my website?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/) A question must be always self-containing. As such add your CSS to the [repro].

Comment: Is there some missing code? I can't see anywhere that the user can actually type in their email address - I was expecting an input element or some other editable element.

Comment: please go to https://evolvereacademy.com , you can see "enter your email" that is not working

Answer (score -1):

First of all, The input isn't clickable because it isn't even an input. It's just a blank piece of text. So you could replace the text with a input box. Here, I made one based on your code.
`<input class="text-2" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email address here">`
You can remove the class and add it to the div or remove the entire div tag and just leave the class there. What ever works best for you.
***Hope this helps!***

Comment: you guessing into the blue. there so many was in making any element clickable. The easiest will proberly remain to use an anchor or to use the `onclick`-attribute. However the initial question remains: **what does the OP expect to heppen`? what does he try to achieve?**